# What are some of the most efficient ways to store a grid-like structure in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Suppose I had multiple NxN grids and I wanted to manipulate particular locations in them based on some commands.  What are some of the most efficient ways I can do so in C++?

To make things clearer, consider I have the following file:

world.txt:

```
2 O O
O O O
X O X
-----
X O X
O O O
1 O O
```

Which represents two 3x3 grids.  Also suppose, for the sake of clarity (but it doesn't really matter) that my task was to implement an algorithm that prints the locations taken to get from 1 to 2 (using whatever route).  What's the most efficient way to store this kind of data in C++ and act on individual locations based on some rules?  What data structures are good at working with data that has this form?

Comment: If I have to do this, I would design an own 'grid' class using a simple array.

Comment: What is *efficient* for you ? Memory-efficient ? Fast for your usecase ? Fast for a set of usecases ?

Comment: Efficient in terms of execution time (i.e. runs fastest for at most 50  NxN grids).

Comment: ... efficient in memory, efficient for insertions/deletions, ....

Comment: What operations do you have to perform on that grid? Is it always quadrilateral (i.e. a structured mesh), or could it be unstructured? Triangles? Arbitrary shapes? If it's a graph problem use a dedicated library, such as [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph).

Comment: That depends. On how many objects there are in the grid, compared to the size of the grid. And on how many differnt objects there are. And of course it depends on the size of the grid, if efficiency matters at all. For a 3x3 grid I would not even start to bother.

Comment: @ArneMertz then consider 40 1000x1000 grids...

Comment: Can it be sparse? Do you need fast row/column insertion/removal?

Comment: Yes, particular locations need to be replaced with something else.

Comment: Choosing the right data structure is highly dependent on what you need to do with that data structure, so the algorithm *does* matter. It's also dependent on what's being stored in the data structure, and how many, and ... In other words - if you want an efficient data structure for your purposes, you'll need to be more clear about what your purposes are - and if you don't know yet, then whatever choice you make should be good enough for now.

Comment: OK, then suppose I wanted to find the shortest route from 1 to 2, replacing my path with Hs.

Comment: Instead of looking for the best grid representation, consider looking first for a efficient algorithm to solve the problem. Maybe you will find a good fitting graph algorithm to this problem, then you would need to transform the grid into a graph structure.

Answer (score 0):

For space efficiency, or speed of access, (or pretty much anything else) you're not going to beat a 2D array.  What a more complicated structure would grant you would is a more intuitive representation of the problem, at the cost of some space or speed.

By way of illustration, consider representing your grid as a graph, each node (vertex) having a list of pointers (edges) to its neighbors.  In this representation, you can cast your problem as a graph problem and do things (say, a Dijkstra shortest-path search) in a more easily conceptualized way, since the representation is explicitly a graph.  Leaving it as a 2D array, you gain storage efficiency at the cost of some complexity, since you'd have to, for example, explicitly encode the adjacency rules (nodes on corners have 2 neighbors, nodes on edges 3, etc.) and graph traversal rules in your program logic.

---

For something simple like this I'd stick with an array.  But that's entirely personal preference.  I can see how, if you were going for something more expository a graph representation would be better.  (Plus it generalizes better to arbitrary configurations.)

Comment: I'd also note that for speed of access, you need to get the grid the right way around in memory. If you allocate each row separately, you want to be traversing each row, not traversing each column, then incrementing the column number. This aligns in cache much better, prevents as many lines being falsely evicted from cache, and works with prefetch much better.

Comment: True.  Graph problems though usually entail fairly random access to the nodes, and for the problem sizes he's mentioning (50x50), it's all going to be in L1 anyways.  If you were really masochistic (or really anal about cache locality), try traversing in Morton order: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_(curve)